# Conflict on using ParentDataModifiers together

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-modifier, jetpack-compose-modifier

I have a composable function like this:

```kotlin
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .align(Alignment.End),
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(text = "My Button")
        }
    }
```

And my button is aligned to the end of screen correctly. Now when I add `layoutId("button")` to the button's modifier before `.align(Alignment.End)` line, my button aligns to the **start** of screen. It appears that every modifier that is extended from `ParentDataModifier` overrides `parentData` and we cannot use them together.

So Is this an intentional behavior or am I missing something?